# need to access second degree json field but code is only set up for first

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to pass a function the identifier to access the field "yrhiprice" in this (very simplified) json quote object:

```
quote: {
        "last": "49.65",
        "FundamentalData": {
          "yrhiprice": "49.77000"
        }
      }
```

the function that i'm passing to, which I can't edit, accesses these fields based on the data-field I put into a table cell:

```
<td data-field="last"></td>
```

and the (very simplified) function, which I can't edit, just takes whatever's in the data-field attribute and uses it as the key to access the fields in the object

```
var name = $elt.data('field');    
var value = (quote[name]) ? (quote[name]) : '---';
$elt.text(value);
```

so, my rather ridiculous question: is there any way to access the "yrhiprice" field, even though it's only going to drop it into the first set of brackets?

I've tried "FundamentalData["yrhiprice"]", "FundamentalData.yrhiprice", and "FundamentalData][yrhiprice" with no luck.

Thanks so much!

Comment: `quote.FundamentalData.yrhiprice` and `quote.last` should work without problem. `console.log()`?

Comment: Wouldn't `"FundamentalData][yrhiprice"` be `"FundamentalData"]["yrhiprice"`? Even though it's a silly way to do things.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I can't console.log() anything because I can't edit the javascript, just pass it whatever's in the data-field attribute.

Comment: @Andy: Why can't you edit the javascript? Even if you can access the server hosting the `.js` file, you could inline a replacement function.

Comment: '"FundamentalData"]["yrhiprice"' I tried that using escapes to try and break out of the quotes, but it didn't work - I'm guessing because it's just reading the whole thing as a string?

And yes, a very silly way to do things, but it's what I'm stuck with at the moment...

Comment: Can't edit because it's above my paygrade, so to speak, and it's kind of hard to get the person who can to do it.

Comment: @Andy: So? Just write your own replacement function inline in a script tag in your HTML after you load their library.

Comment: Did you decode the json string with for example `jQuery.parseJSON()` before trying to use it?

Comment: The decoding is being done in the part I can't access. Basically, the HTML is rendered, then an AJAX function goes over and fills in the fields, so I'm pretty much stuck with whatever it puts in the fields. I'm not sure I can write a function to catch it before it fills in the cell...

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, but either way thanks so much you guys' help!

Comment: Maybe you could use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/

Comment: Thanks, looking into it now.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit the function and `FundamentalData.yrhiprice` doesn't work, you could just flatten your object so the the `yrhiprice` property is copied up a level. Obviously this will only work if all the property names you need to copy are unique, but even in that case, you'd just have to take care to prefix or suffix your properties with something to make them unique.

So if you have a `quote` object, could you:

```
myQuote.FundamentalData_yrhiprice = myQuote.FundamentalData.yrhiprice;
```

and then:

```
<td data-field="FundamentalData_yrhiprice">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "FundamentalData";
var val = quote[name];
val = val.yrhiprice; //"49.77000"
```